# Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/VERDE_mc2.bin

Tags: kernel, ati, radeon, firmware

I have this missing firmware after compiling and installing kernel 3.14.6 (mainline)

Could someone point me to where I can get it or how to make it get compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the Radeon firmwares are available at http://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/